# Single Sign On with Identity Provider vs Integrated Windows Authentication with IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, single-sign-on, adfs

I'm working on on-premise web application (front end hosted on IIS) that currently uses traditional form-based authentication. Our client wants the application to support "single sign on", which basically means he wants the users to automatically log in to the application. AFAIK there are two ways I can take to achieve the desired effect:

1. Most articles that I found suggest using some kind of Identity Provider system (like Active Directory Federated Services), which my application can communicate with over SAML/OIDC in order to obtain user's claims.
2. On the other hand, I could set up IIS to use Integrated Windows Authentication and get user claims directly from Active Directory through Kerberos/NTLM. This approach seems easier.

Given that my application will not be used outside of intranet, it is hosted in environments using Microsoft products (Active Directory, Windows Server, users using Windows machines), is there any reason I should consider the first approach?

Comment: Active Directory Federation Services allows sharing of identity information outside a company's network. It authenticates users with their usernames and passwords. compared with the second method, I still think the second method is safer.

Comment: @samwu: Both ADFS and Kerberos ultimately authenticate users with their usernames and passwords (though I believe ADFS can itself use Kerberos/NTLM), and both potentially allow "outside" sharing – but only _if_ the company has set it up... as far as I know, ADFS won't send tokens to SPs it doesn't recognize, so if the company doesn't want sharing, they will simply not enable it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, if you have any questions, welcome to discuss.